# DBIx Class: overloading new() in a resultset

Tags: resultset, dbix-class

Hello dear community members.

I have a following problem. Say, I have a user table. During my programming I create a lot of search queries to this table. Then, later, I realize that I need to select always only "active" users, i.e. with "active" column set to TRUE. Now, instead of adjusting all my queries to the user table with additional filter (active => "true"), is it possible to overload new() in the resultset class or to do something that will globally change all my queries in the way I need?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to your User ResultSet class that returns a filtered resultset, for example:

```
sub search_active {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->search({ active => 1 });
}
```

Also see the DBIx::Class docs on 'predefined searches' for more information.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. But this is not quite what I need. I have already a lot of existing queries. Now, instead of changing them all one by one, I need a single place in the code where I can make a change, that will affect all my EXISTING queries.

Comment: From my experience you regret that later when you do need a query that doesn't only require active rows. If you're using Catalyst it's the perfect use case for Chained with this filter applied to a stashed resultset quite at the top of your action chain.

Comment: If you know in advance what you need, then yes, you can filter the resultset in the Chained, but not when you need to do this retrospectively.